# What type conversion happen when I assign a short to a char?

Tags: c++, types, casting

What type conversion happen if I have the following:

```
short s = 1234;
char c = s;
```

Will `s` first gets converted to an `int`, and this `int` gets converted to a `char` and assigned to `c`? Or will `s` just gets converted directly to a `char` and assigned to `c`?

Comment: char is just an 8-bit integer, short is a 16 bit integer, so with number < 256 nothing will happen, but numbers bigger than 255 the result will be truncated. as an example is you have the short 0xabcd, the result will be 0xab (host byte order).

Comment: @ichramm on most systems the result will be `(char)0xcd`

Comment: @ichramm: Rather, `char` is not guaranteed to have more than 8, nor `short` to have more than 16 bits. At least the first is guaranteed to be no bigger than the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s` does not get converted to `int`.

Here<sup>1</sup> we are initializing `c` with a value that is out of range for `char`. Plain `char` can either be signed or unsigned (most compilers have a switch to toggle this). If `char` is signed then the relevent standard text is in [conv.integral]/3:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

"implementation-defined" means that your compiler must document what happens here. A common implementation on modern systems is that excess bits will be truncated, starting at the most significant end.

It's a good idea to rewrite this code to not rely on implementation-defined behaviour; so that the behaviour doesn't change when you go to compile it on a different system.

If `char` is unsigned then the previous paragraph covers the case:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]

so the resulting char value would be 1234 - 1024 = `210` .

---

<sup>1</sup> This post assumes you're on a system with 8-bit bytes. There are a few specialized chips around where that is not the case, and on those systems, `char` could hold a value of `1234` just fine with no value changes required.